# PDF Generation: fit table to page

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf

I have to export a table with **dynamic count of rows** to a PDF that must **fit on one page**.

Currently, I'm generating an HTML document, wrapping the table within a `<div>` and then using CSS `zoom` to zoom out; the percentage is calculated with the count of rows. This HTML is then converted to PDF via wkhtmltopdf.

I need a better solution because the `zoom` calculation is not very reliable. Some rows are displayed higher than others and also wkhtmltopdf has some rendering troubles when using zoom.

I looked in the docs of *FOP, iText* and some other libraries/tools but couldn't find a solution.

*Only requirement: It has to run on a Linux machine.*

Thanks!

Comment: When in the process are you calculating the zoom factor? You might want to do this using JavaScript, after the document is loaded. That way, you know exactly the height of the table.

Comment: that's so obvious but I didn't think about it.
Good idea! I'll try that

Comment: stwagner: I was wondering if you could share your final solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: final solution is still on its way, I was interrupted by other problems